# jquery add style to element if html body has a class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add style to element with jquery but only then if HTML body has a class list active. But my code doesn't work maybe you got any ideas whats wrong with it?

```
<script>
   $(init);

   function init() {
   if ($("body").hasClass("product-type-gift-card")){
   $(".etheme-sticky-cart").css("display:none");
   }};
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? When does that code run?

Comment: No error, the code should be active all the time and after opening specific product page it supposed to hide element in that page

Comment: Use css:  `body.product-type-gift-card .etheme-sticky-cart { display:none; }`

Comment: `.css("display:none");` is not how you use the css method.  Either `.css("display", "none")` or `.css({ "display" : "none" })`